# how to send body parameter with multipart file upload request in OKhttp

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I am trying to upload a file using multipart request in okhttp.
using below code.

```
public static Boolean uploadFile(String serverURL, File file) {
    try {

        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
                .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("file", file.getName(),
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/csv"), file))
                .addFormDataPart("some-field", "some-value")
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(serverURL)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                // Handle the error
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Handle the error
                }
                // Upload successful
            }
        });

        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Handle the error
    }
    return false;
}
```

which is working file.

**My problem is- i also wants to send some key value pair in body parameters but it is creating problem in request.**

I am using below code to append key value body parameters in multipart request.

```
FormBody.Builder formBodyBuilder = new FormBody.Builder();
formBodyBuilder.add("name", "Mac");
requestBody.addPart(formBodyBuilder.build());
```

but it is creating problem.
Any help will really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I am doing this with Okhttp3 and it works fine:

```
MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse(MIME_TYPE);
        MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("type", stringsToPost[0])
                ...
                .addFormDataPart("file", file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, file));
```

Comment: How can we add one more file with the same name

Answer (score 2):

you try this

```
RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("grant_type", "")
        .add("username", "")
        .add("password", "")
        .build();
RequestBody requestBodyy = new MultipartBody.Builder()
        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        .addPart(
                Headers.of("content-type", "form-data; name=\"image\""),
                RequestBody.create(null, "Square Logo"))
        .addPart(
                Headers.of("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"),
                formBody)
        .build();
```